# Java Split and Replace String

Tags: java, replace, split, midp, removing-whitespace

I got a string variable. The example of the string is like this:

```
abc
12345 cde123
hyz 
8755 3356
```

and I want to assign an array string by splitting the whitespace become like this. And I want to take just first 4 values of it.

```
stringArray[0] = abc;
stringArray[1] = 12345;
stringArray[2] = cde123;
stringArray[3] = hyz;
```

8755 3356  not need to assign in this array string.

However, the `abc` and `12345` is seperate by a newline and not a whitespace. So i try to replace the newline become whitespace with my function, which is like this:

```
Util.replaceStr(stringX, "\n", " ");
```

To assign spilt the string into array string, i detect the index of white space which is

```
int index= sMessage.indexOf(" ");
```

And put it on looping

```
stringArray[i] = stringX.substring(0,index);
stringX=stringX.substring(index,stringX.length()-index);
index =stringX.indexOf(" ");
```

and assign the first 4 values into it. However after i replace the newline into whitespace, there will be double whitespace and the first four array will get like this

```
stringArray[0] = abc;
stringArray[1] = ;
stringArray[2] = 12345;
stringArray[3] = cde123;
```

How can i assign the array string by skipping the white space value?
**THERE IS NO SPLIT FUNCTION IN NETBEAN**. I know java got. =)

Comment: What's netbean? Can't find that on google. Do you mean Netbeans? This is an IDE, an application, not a language...

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: This example should work with a target of Java 1.1

```
String text = "String text2 = text.replaceAll(\"[^\\p{Alpha} ]\", \"\");";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
    char ch = text.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(ch) || Character.isWhitespace(ch))
        sb.append(ch);
}
String text2 = sb.toString();
System.out.println(text2);
```

prints

```
String text  textreplaceAllpAlpha
```

---

If you want to split by white space you can use `\s`

```
String text = 
String[] words = text.split("\\s");
```

You appear to have multiple white spaces (There is a space after `hyz`) you can use the `+` to mean one ore more.

```
String text = "abc\n" +
        "12345 cde123\n" +
        "hyz \n" +
        "8755 3356\n";
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

prints

```
[abc, 12345, cde123, hyz, 8755, 3356]
```

Comment: the whitespace is splited but the problem is there will be double whitespace and i dont wan to assign to array string when the value is a white space

Comment: I have added a solution for multiple white spaces. ;)

Comment: The keyword here is [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: in netbean, there is actually dont have the split function

Comment: String.split is a function of Java. It doesn't matter which IDE you are using. Split was added in Java 1.4, ten years ago.  If you have an older JVM (and amazingly some people do) that mighty explain why you can't use split().

Comment: So which version of Java do you have?  If you have an old version of Java you need to say so otherwise you could be wasting your/our time with a solution which won't work for you.

Comment: Java: 1.6.0_24; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 19.1-b02
i am using netbean IDE 6.9.1
and i try to build an very old mobile apps so that the apps can even run on ur nokia 3310

Comment: Ok, so what is your target Java level?

Answer (score 1):

In java there is a library function for splitting , So use that function for splitting. You just replace the new line with white space and use the following function.

```
String[] stringArray  = stringX.split("\\s");
```

Comment: THERE IS NO SPLIT FUNCTION IN NETBEAN

Comment: Split is not a function specified for particular IDE's, It is a method provided by String Class in java. Please go through core java thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

**Using replaces**

After converting all type of spaces to `\n`: You could execute replace `\n\n` with `\n` until the string doesn't change. That way you could assure there's no double spaces.

**Using regex**

You could also use some king of regex pattern to find the words. Something like:

`\S+`

should suffice. You are getting all the non-whitespace chars. If you find the first four regex inside the string you will have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just split around any group of whitespaces (using "+" in the regex). You won't end with groups formed by whitespaces this way.

```
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: THERE IS NO SPLIT FUNCTION IN NETBEAN

Comment: THEN MENTION IT SOMEWHERE BEFORE ASKING :)

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
String[] array = yourString.split("\\s");/* s is uncapitalized.*/
```

`\s` means: **A whitespace character, short for [ \t\n\x0b\r\f]**

You can see http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html for more information.

Comment: THERE IS NO SPLIT FUNCTION IN NETBEAN

Comment: `Java` differ from its `IDEA`, You have to know first `java api  & spec`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 **Stream**, it becomes one liner. Below code splits the whole string based on dots `.` , and then removes all preceding zeroes `0`.

```
// "10.013.00400.0.1.001.100" ---> [10, 13, 400, 0, 1, 1, 100]
String in = "10.013.00400.0.1.001.100"; 
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(in.split("\\."))
                          .map(s -> s.replaceAll("^0+(?!$)", ""))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[10, 13, 400, 0, 1, 1, 100]
```